# How can I use variable from other page on Webservice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I found a webservice example(and edited for me) like this:

MyServiceClass.cs:

```
[WebService]
public class DBStatus
{
    [WebMethod]
    public Status[] StatusXML()
    {
        Status[] stts = new Status[] {
            new Status() {
                DB = "DB1",
                NODE = "TRUE",
                FTP = "TRUE",
                PROCESS = "TRUE"
            }
        };
        return stts;
    }
}
```

Status.cs:

```
public class Status
{
    public string DB { get; set; }
    public string NODE { get; set; }
    public string FTP { get; set; }
    public string PROCESS { get; set; }
}
```

Status.asmx:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/MyServiceClass.cs" Class="DBStatus" %>
```

I have a other page and doing something like this (status.aspx.cs):

```
public partial class StatusPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public char v3;
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection Connection3;
        using (Connection3 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=DATABASE1:1521/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;Password=PASSWORD;User ID=USERNAME"))
        {
            Connection3.Open();
            v3 = "online";
            Connection3.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        v3 = "offline";
    }
}
```

I need to use this variable on webservice like this:

```
DB="this is v3 variable from status.aspx.cs (like online/offline)"
NODE="this is other variable from status.aspx.cs",
FTP="this is other variable from status.aspx.cs",
PROCESS="this is other variable from status.aspx.cs"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Pages should not need to refer to each other in a properly architected system. You can pass data around with query string or store it in Session.

Comment: Can you please show me example for this?

Comment: Store a variable in session is `Session["myvariable"] = variable;` and retrieving a value is `var variable = Session["myvariable"];`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change [WebMethod] to [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] and then save your shared variables in the Session.